# "Missing Mono Script" and "The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing" errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following a tutorial to make a 2D platformer. I installed the bayatGames asset package and wanted to run the 'demo' project they created. However, I get multiple errors saying the same thing: "The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing!". From what I understand, the script that's meant to be attached to these objects is not available, but I don't understand why? I haven't edited the asset package, this is just how it was downloaded. ([picture of what my project looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbBBb.png)) this error also means I can't see the character's objects on my screen. What's causing this issue? The unity version I am running is 2019.3.15f1.

Comment: try and reapply the appropriate script to the gameobject. The file has moved somewhere else or is otherwise unavailable.

Comment: Did you also import the "scripts" folder? Also, did you copy/paste in your folder explorator of windows or in unity? Because if you didnt copy/paste folder into unity directly, it vwon't work since script are not linked to it

Answer (score 0):

A frequent cause of this error is when the file name of the script containing a Monobehaviour class does not match the Monobehaviour class name (minus the .cs extension, of course).

This can also be caused by a compiler error, but that would likely show up in the console as such.